# c++ vector's member are not updating

Tags: c++

Im trying to write a adjacency matrix representation using vectors of integer vectors , therefore vector> . However when I add members to the vector and later try and print those values nothing has changed. Most likely it has to do with "pass by value" however I have used "pass by reference" to the best of my knowledge.

**Here is my header:**

```
#ifndef GRAPH_MATRIX
    #define GRAPH_MATRIX
    #include <vector>
    //header for graph represented via adjacency matrix with minimal functionality 
    class graph
    {
        public:
        graph(int);
        ~graph();
        void add_edge(int v1, int v2, int weight); 
        void print_graph();

        private:
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> vertex_matrix; 
        int num_of_vertices;
        int num_of_edges; 


    };

#endif
```

**the cpp implementation file:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "graph_matrix.h"
#include <climits>
using namespace std;
//header for graph represented via adjacency matrix with minimal functionality 

graph::graph(int _num_of_vertices) : num_of_vertices(_num_of_vertices)
    {

        if (_num_of_vertices==0)
        {
            _num_of_vertices=10;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < _num_of_vertices; i++)
        {
             vertex_matrix.push_back(vector<int> (_num_of_vertices,INT_MAX));
        }

    }

    graph::~graph()
    {
    vertex_matrix.clear(); 
    }

    void graph::add_edge(int v1, int v2, int weight)
    {
        //vertex_matrix[v1-1][v2-1] == INT_MAX 
        vector<int> columnVector = vertex_matrix[v1-1];
        if (columnVector[v2-1] == INT_MAX)
            {
                columnVector[v2-1] = weight;

            }
    }

void graph::print_graph()
{

    for (int i=0; i< vertex_matrix.size(); i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < vertex_matrix.size(); j++)
            {
                //vertex_matrix[i][j]
                std::vector<int> columnVector = vertex_matrix[i]; 

                if (columnVector[j] != INT_MAX)
                {
                    std::cout << columnVector[j] ;  
                }
                else
                {
                        std::cout << "0";
                }


            }

            std::cout << endl; 
    }//end for printing 


}
```

**the main entry:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "graph_matrix.h"
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
std::cout << " Matrix representation of graph" << std::endl;

    graph _graph(4);
    _graph.add_edge(1,2,1);
    _graph.add_edge(2,3,1);
    _graph.add_edge(3,1,1);
    _graph.add_edge(3,3,1);
    _graph.add_edge(3,4,1);
    _graph.add_edge(4,0,0);

    _graph.print_graph(); 


}
```

When I use the print function I currently getting 0's.

How can I make this proper pass by reference, and have the updated values print.

Thanks

Comment: `add_edge` is pointless as-written. All you do is modify a locally declared `columnVector`, then exit the function. the decl `vector<int> columnVector = vertex_matrix[v1-1];`just makes a copy of the data in the member; it doesn't reference it beyond that. You're then modifying the copy, then discarding all of that when the function exits.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, you are creating a copy of your column and then modifying the copy. What you want to do is to make a reference to it.

```
vector<int>& columnVector = vertex_matrix[v1-1];
if (columnVector[v2-1] == INT_MAX)
{
    columnVector[v2-1] = weight;
}
```

Or you can access the element directly.

```
if (vertex_matrix[v1-1][v2-1] == INT_MAX)
{
    vertex_matrix[v1-1][v2-1] = weight;
}
```

In `print_graph` you are doing the same, but here you are not modifying anything so that works, but you are making an unnecessary copy for no reason which is not ideal.

A last point is that you are calling `vertex_matrix.clear()` in your destructor. This is redundant, when the vector goes out of scope it will clear itself up, so you don't need to manage that.